# Balance for each month by type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, in SQL-Server, with several records of input and output values with columns for type and date.

Something like that:

```
DATE       |INPUT  |OUTPUT |TYPE
2018-01-10 | 256.35|       |A
2018-02-05 |       |  35.00|B
2018-02-15 |  65.30|       |A
2018-03-20 | 158.00|       |B
2018-04-02 |       |  63.32|B
2018-05-12 |       | 128.12|A
2018-06-20 |       |   7.35|B
```

I need help to make a query to returns the sum of inputs and outputs (as balance), per type, but it should return that sum **at the end of each month**, that is:

```
YEAR|MONTH|TYPE|BALANCE
2018|    1|A   | 256.35
2018|    1|B   |   0.00
2018|    2|A   | 321.65
2018|    2|B   | -35.00
2018|    3|A   | 321.65
2018|    3|B   | 123.00
2018|    4|A   | 321.65
2018|    4|B   |  59.68
2018|    5|A   | 193.53
2018|    5|B   |  59.68
2018|    6|A   | 193.53
2018|    6|B   |  52.33
2018|    7|A   | 193.53
2018|    7|B   |  52.33
```

Don't forget that the balance of each month is affected by the balance of the previous month, or in other words, the balance of each month is not only the movements of that month but of all the previous months also.

It should also be noted that it should include a record for each month of the year/type (up to the current date), even if a given month/type don't have movements, starting at the first month/year of the oldest movement and ending at actual date (in this case 2018 July).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result achieved, there you go:

```
declare @min_month datetime=(select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,min([DATE])),0) from _yourtable)
declare @max_month datetime=(select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,max([DATE])),0) from _yourtable)

;WITH months(d) AS (
  select @min_month
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateadd(month,1,d) -- Recursion
  FROM months
  where dateadd(month,1,d)<=getdate()
)
select distinct
    year(m.d) as YEAR,
    month(m.d) as MONTH,
    types.v as [TYPE]
    ,sum(isnull(t.[INPUT],0)-isnull(t.[OUTPUT],0)) over (partition by types.v order by m.d)
from months m
cross join (select distinct type from _yourtable)types(v)
left join _yourtable t on dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,t.[DATE]),0)=m.d and types.v=t.TYPE
order by m.d,type
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @George Menoutis, it's almost perfect! The values ar correct but in some months it returns severals records for the same type.

Comment: *ahh, right. Try adding distinct after the select*  - This is lazy coding and has the potential to cause significant performance problems

Comment: Working perfect with select distinct statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lag function, below code might help:

```
select year(date), month(date), type
, sum(input-output) + isnull(lag(sum(input-output),1,0) over(order by year(date), month(date), type), 0)
from test group by year(date), month(date), type
```

Comment: Almost there, but there are two problems: one, big problem, the values are not correct. The other one, no results for months that have no movements...

Comment: Try using below query, it will give you correct results. However, it will still return data for the year/month/type for which there is data in the table. `select year(date), month(date), type
, sum(isnull(input,0)-isnull(output,0)) + isnull(lag(sum(isnull(input,0)-isnull(output,0)),1,0) over(partition by type order by year(date), month(date), type), 0)
from test group by year(date), month(date), type`

Comment: The values still wrong... no problem with the other issue, but the maths needs to be perfect.

Comment: Thanks @Alankrit to introduce to me the `LAG` function. After a closer look, I noticed that after the month(s) when there are no movements of a certain type, the `LAG` function returns to zero instead of fetching the last value. So the math was not right, as I had said... any idea to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source data is in the structure you have initially provided (ie: this is not the result of another query), this is a fairly straightforward transformation using a table of dates and a running total via an ordered `sum`.

If you already have a dates table, you can remove the first 2 `cte`s in this script:

```
declare @t table(DateValue date,InputAmount decimal(8,2),OutputAmount decimal(8,2),ProdType nvarchar(1));
insert into @t values
 ('2018-01-10',256.35,null,'A')
,('2018-02-05',null, 35.00,'B')
,('2018-02-15', 65.30,null,'A')
,('2018-03-20',158.00,null,'B')
,('2018-04-02',null, 63.32,'B')
,('2018-05-12',null,128.12,'A')
,('2018-06-20',null,  7.35,'B')
;

-- Min date can just be min date in the source table, but the max date should be the month end of the max date in the source table0
declare @MinDate date = (select min(DateValue) from @t);
declare @MaxDate date = (select max(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,DateValue)+1,0))) from @t);

with n(n) as (select * from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(t))   -- Using a tally table, built a table of dates
    ,d(d) as (select top(select datediff(day,@MinDate,@MaxDate)+1) dateadd(day,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,@MinDate) from n n1,n n2,n n3, n n4)
    ,m as (select p.ProdType                                                        -- Then join to the source data to create a date value for each posible day for each product type
                    ,d.d
                    ,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,d)+1,0)) as m    -- And calculate a running total using a windowed aggregate
                    ,sum(isnull(t.InputAmount,0) - isnull(t.OutputAmount,0)) over (partition by p.ProdType order by d.d) as RunningTotal
            from d
                cross join (select distinct ProdType
                            from @t
                            ) as p
                left join @t as t
                    on d.d = t.DateValue
                        and p.ProdType = t.ProdType
            )
select m
        ,ProdType
        ,RunningTotal as Balance
from m
where m = d
order by m.d
        ,m.ProdType;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+----------+---------+
|            m            | ProdType | Balance |
+-------------------------+----------+---------+
| 2018-01-31 00:00:00.000 | A        |  256.35 |
| 2018-01-31 00:00:00.000 | B        |    0.00 |
| 2018-02-28 00:00:00.000 | A        |  321.65 |
| 2018-02-28 00:00:00.000 | B        |  -35.00 |
| 2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 | A        |  321.65 |
| 2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 | B        |  123.00 |
| 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 | A        |  321.65 |
| 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000 | B        |   59.68 |
| 2018-05-31 00:00:00.000 | A        |  193.53 |
| 2018-05-31 00:00:00.000 | B        |   59.68 |
| 2018-06-30 00:00:00.000 | A        |  193.53 |
| 2018-06-30 00:00:00.000 | B        |   52.33 |
+-------------------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: It is funny you comment me about distinct, yet you provide a code that does the same. In OP's example, there are no rows sharing the same type and month(date). However, OP obviously has such cases in their db, and that's where the multiple rows come from. How have you prevented this?

Comment: I've tried this query and it's working too. However, I do not consider it the best answer because it does not return year / month but rather the date of the last day of the month and in addition it seems to me that it takes more time to execute (in my database) than the query of @George.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis  Follow the code and you will see that each `type` is calculated for each `date` and then totaled up into month ends.  If you can't see how this works, add some additional dummy data in and test for yourself.  Despite looking similar, my code is actually considerably different to yours.

Comment: @PJLG  If you needed `year` and `month` you can just use the `year()` and `month()` function.  It practice however, it is rare that you don't want to actually return a `date` value when you are wanting to represent a date value.